# This is declaring a variable - right?

Tags: javascript, variables

On a blog I see the following:

```
for (var key in map) {
  if (map.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var value = map[key];
    // right, now we can get some work done
  }
}
```

> "Now you see that var key at the top of the for loop? That’s not
>   declaring a variable, oh no. It’s saying that somewhere else there’s a
>   variable called key"

Surely this is declaring a variable (if one named `key` did not previously exist in the scope chain)? What might the author mean by this?

Link: http://dannorth.net/2011/12/19/the-rise-and-rise-of-javascript/

Comment: Do you have a link to the post in question? You are right, that is a declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Surely this is declaring a variable (if one named key did not previously exist in the scope chain)?

Yes, it is, within the function that `for` loop is in. (The variable is **not** limited to the `for` loop like it would be in, say, Java. Its scope is the *entire* function it's in.)

More about `var` (on my blog): [*Poor, misunderstood `var`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html)

> What might the author mean by this?

It sounds sarcastic, actually, like the author is trying to make a point by saying the opposite of what they mean.

**Edit** Since you've posted the link, here's the *complete* quote:

> Now you see that `var` key at the top of the `for` loop? That’s not declaring a variable, oh no. It’s saying that *somewhere else* there’s a variable called `key` (right at the top of the nearest containing function, it turns out). Oh, and that `key` variable is visible all through that function, and any functions it contains, not just tucked away in the for loop. Brilliant!

The point he's trying to make there is that the variable isn't just limited to the `for` loop. But that initial statement is flatly incorrect. I know what he means, but it's not what he said.

---

Re the first point above, in ES6 JavaScript will be getting a new keyword, `let`, which would declare something *only* for the `for` loop:

```
// New in ES6, you probably can't use this yet
for (let key in map) {
//   ^^^---------------- change is here
  if (map.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    let value = map[key];
//  ^^^----------------- probably want to change this one, too
    // right, now we can get some work done
  }
}
```

Some engines already support it, but you can't use it broadly yet, as many don't. And in theory the ES6 draft spec could change, though I really doubt it will. :-)

Answer (score 1):

That, actually is a full definition of a variable from an iterator value that's fetched at the current iteration of variable map. It's a declaration + initialization.

To understand the notion of iterators you would have to go deeper and look into the underlying interpreter code which supports the value of the key to every iteration of the loop.

Also this: "Now you see that var key at the top of the for loop? That’s not declaring a variable, oh no. It’s saying that somewhere else there’s a variable called key" sounds stupid, doesn't explain anything and creates confusion.

I wouldn't read such articles, because such a statement shows that the author isn't really acquainted with the real world behind JavaScript - that is C/C++ or even assembly, which work at the basic memory level, and use constructs called iterators to support values to loops in case of data structures that are more advanced than simple arrays.